# How to conditionally show a dialog based on if a feature is selected, Installshield

Tags: window, installation, conditional-statements

I am new to using installshield (2012) and am having difficulty doing something - google searches don't seem to turn anything up which is strange because I'm trying to do something quite common.

Basically I am trying to only show a new custom dialog in my installer based on when a feature is set to be installed. (It is to gather a string input that holds the location of a db). You can set the conditions for a dialog when adding it in the wizard so I could select

```
_IsSetupTypeMin = Complete
```

Which would show the dialog when all features are installed. However If the user selects 'custom install' and still selects the feature to be installed it should still show the dialog. I don't understand how individual features being installed get stored in a property or how you might go about referencing whether or not that feature is installed so cannot write a statement for this.

Sorry if this is a simple question, work has asked me to do this and InstallShield seems very unintuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the "&" prefix will give the action state of a feature. The value 3 represents the INSTALLSTATE_LOCAL and means that the feature is installing on the local computer.

For example, the conditional expression "&MyFeature=3" evaluates to True only if MyFeature is changing from its current state to the state of being installed on the local computer, INSTALLSTATE_LOCAL.

Here's the "Conditional Statement Syntax" article with related information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This didn't work for me at all. I had to use a custom action to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok eventually I found the solution. Simply use an ampersand followed by your features name and then append '=3'. The three represents it is to be installed. The & tells InstallShield it is a features name.

therefore:

```
&FeatureName = 3
```

I hope this helps anyone else as it was difficult to find a solution, and seeing as though it seems to be a very common issue im sure other people will appreciate knowing this.